# Why my loop is just running once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why my loop is just running once?

```
var resultado = [];
var cartela = [];

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  var sorteados = Math.round(Math.random() * (59 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  resultado.push(sorteados);

  var pessoa = prompt("Digite um número");
  cartela.push(pessoa);
}

console.log("Os números sorteados são: " + resultado);
console.log("Seus números: " + cartela);
```

When I created a second loop for

```
var pessoa = prompt("Digite um número");
cartela.push(pessoa);
```

I noticed that the error is here, but do not know why

Comment: No, your loop is running six times ?

Comment: `prompt` blocks JS execution. You will have to close the dialog in order to continue iterating.

Comment: Also, do you have the do-not-prompt-again checkbox enabled?

Comment: i want to prompt six times, but somehow the prompt is breaking my loop. i want to get six numbers in array cartela and resultado.

Comment: nevermind guys, i've to put // noprotect inside my code on JSBIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Prompt` blocks the loop execution. In fact, it blocks the whole JS execution.

If the box is not appearing, you must have checked the "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs". You can reset this by closing and opening again the same tab.

If you comment the line where the prompt is, and the following one, the loop should iterate 6 times.

```
//var pessoa = prompt("Digite um número");
//cartela.push(pessoa);
```

EDIT: trying your code in a Google Chrome console, prompts 6 times for a number and returns the following:

```
Os números sorteados são: 22,32,25,45,3,43
Seus números: 2,3,4,1,5,6
```

Try it yourself there. Your code is OK. It must be the `prevent this page from creating additional dialogs` issue